# Web Essentials + js bundles = publish error

Tags: javascript, .net, web-essentials

I've got a VS solution; which contains multiple projects. In one of those projects, i've used a .bundle with Web Essentials to combine and minify some JS files. I can build and publish this project no problem. However, when I come to publish any of the other projects, I get an error telling me 'bundle error the file '/assets/js/jsfile.js' doesn't exist'

Is there some way to set the other project to ignore .bundle files?